# Get object key in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

If I have an object like the following:

```
languages = {
    "ar":{
        "name":"Arabic",
        "nativeName":"العربية"
    },
    "bg":{
        "name":"Bulgarian",
        "nativeName":"български език"
    },
    "ca":{
        "name":"Catalan; Valencian",
        "nativeName":"Català"
    }...
}
```

And I loop through it in a list like so:

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="lang in languages"><a ng-click="select(lang)">{{lang.nativeName}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Is there a way to get the object key in the select function without also putting the key in the object itself?

i.e:

```
languages = {
        "ar":{
            "name":"Arabic",
            "nativeName":"العربية",
            "key":"ar"
        },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, lang) in languages"><a ng-click="select(key)">{{lang.nativeName}}</a></li>
 </ul>
```